# setCloseButtonIcon(Bitmap drawable) is not working with SVGs in ChromeCustomTab

Tags: android, android-bitmap, chrome-custom-tabs, androidsvg

I need to change the default cross-icon in ChromeCustomTab Android, I am changing it with back-icon using the code below:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
```

It is working fine with PNGs but not with SVGs.

As per this documentation, we have to maintain size of image according to this documentation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.html#KEY_ICON

I think it is not working because they are not following the dimensions given in Documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a valid `Bitmap`. For a `VectorDrawable` it is necessary to do something more. You can use these methods:

```
private static Bitmap bitmapFromDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        return bitmapFromVectorDrawable((VectorDrawable) drawable);
    }
    return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static Bitmap bitmapFromVectorDrawable(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
builder.setCloseButtonIcon(bitmapFromDrawable(this, R.drawable. ic_arrow_back_white_24dp));
```