# Chrome Custom Tabs change the default close button not working

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to change the default close button on the actionbar of the custom chrome tabs. I have tried to set using `setCloseButtonIcon()` However, the default close button still shows. I want to change the close to an arrow.

My code below:

```
public void openHomePage() {
    final CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.primary));
    final Bitmap backButton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_48dp);
    builder.setCloseButtonIcon(backButton);

    builder.setShowTitle(true);
    final CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();

    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse(mTvHomepage.getText().toString()));
}
```

Comment: i just checked my code for this and it looks exactly the same. Have you tried another drawable (maybe a smaller one? could this be your problem that the 48dp arrow is to big?)

Comment: @stamanuel First I tried 24dp which didn't work. After some searching someone said use 48dp. However, the 48dp didn't work either.

Comment: Can you post a basic project?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have an observation. Last month, when searching through [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-custom-tabs?sort=newest) for various chrome custom tab issues, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35259612) suggesting to use 24dp size icon and also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42330238) saying that it is working fine with PNG.

I have checked your code with using back arrow icon from [**here**.](https://material.io/icons/#ic_arrow_back)

When I used **"ic_arrow_back_black_48dp"**, it didn't change the default close button to an arrow (see left image).

```
final Bitmap backButton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_48dp);
```

But when I used **"ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"**, it perfectly changed the default close button to an arrow (see right image).

```
final Bitmap backButton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
```

As it has worked perfectly for me, you should also try with **"24dp"** size back arrow icon from [**here**](https://material.io/icons/#ic_arrow_back) instead of **"48dp"** size back arrow icon.

*Screenshot* : [ Device: ASUS_Z00UD; OS: 6.0.1 ]

[image: The default close button has changed to an arrow when using 24dp size icon instead of 48dp size.]

Comment: @FantasyPollock Its seems that you can only use the png icons. I was originally trying to use the svg icons. When I changed to png it started working. Not sure why the svg doesn't work. I used the same icon as you but selected the png. Did you test with the svg icons? Thanks.

Comment: @ant2009 Sorry that I forgot to mention about .png format. Yes, I always tested with png icon. Not sure why the svg icon doesn't work.

Comment: +1 I second what everyone has been saying here. If you want to change the "close icon", it has to be a 24dp  PNG drawable. Vectors or any other size don't work...

Answer (score 9):

Presuming you are using the [Google](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client) library and not on of the related ones the icons size should be 24dp as [documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.html#KEY_ICON).

This can be achieved with BitmapFactory Options:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.outWidth = 24;
options.outHeight = 24;
options.inScaled = true; //already default, just for illustration - ie scale to screen density (dp)
... = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_48dp, opts);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can directly get `BitmapDrawable` from `Drawable` but not from `VectorDrawable` as `setCloseButtonIcon` requires `@NonNull Bitmap icon`

You can also use **svg** as follows. Download the svg from here [ic_arrow_back_black_24px](https://material.io/icons/#ic_arrow_back)

Below methods are self explanatory:

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
  return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
} else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
  return getBitmapFromVectorDrawable((VectorDrawable) drawable);
} else {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to convert to bitmap");
}
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
    vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
return bitmap;
}
```

You can use the above as:

```
builder.setCloseButtonIcon(getBitmapFromDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24px));
```

[Ref from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696488/getting-bitmap-from-vector-drawable)

Answer (score 4):

To make this work in Kotlin (using [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx)) with *any* 24dp drawable resource:

```
AppCompatResources.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp)?.let {
    builder.setCloseButtonIcon(it.toBitmap())
}
```

And if you need to do some tinting:

```
AppCompatResources.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp)?.mutate()?.let {
    DrawableCompat.setTint(it, Color.WHITE)
    builder.setCloseButtonIcon(it.toBitmap())
}
```

If the drawable needs to be resized, then pass in the new width/height to the `Drawable.toBitmap()` function.

And if you are not using Kotlin then you can just use the equivalent of the `Drawable.toBitmap()` code:

```
fun Drawable.toBitmap(
    @Px width: Int = intrinsicWidth,
    @Px height: Int = intrinsicHeight,
    config: Config? = null
): Bitmap {
    if (this is BitmapDrawable) {
        if (config == null || bitmap.config == config) {
            // Fast-path to return original. Bitmap.createScaledBitmap will do this check, but it
            // involves allocation and two jumps into native code so we perform the check ourselves.
            if (width == intrinsicWidth && height == intrinsicHeight) {
                return bitmap
            }
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true)
        }
    }

    val (oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom) = bounds

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config ?: Config.ARGB_8888)
    setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
    draw(Canvas(bitmap))

    setBounds(oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom)
    return bitmap
}
```

For more see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51742167/444761) answer.

Answer (score 3):

why not you Add Image Asset and store in mipmap then it will be easier to use default icons inbuilt in android studio
[Assest Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNqKC.png)

After Uploading You can easily access icons and image from mipmap in xml file using src resource in ImageView for an instant

```
android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had to face the same problem

Solution :-

1) Take `image(back arrow)` in `png` format.
2) Keep the image size under `24dp` .

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has already been answered, since I had this problem too and none of the above suggestions solved my Problem I want to share the way I solved my problem. Hope it helps others.

[Ref](https://medium.com/swlh/using-custom-chrome-tabs-in-your-android-app-b31e4f8f5194)

```
  fun Context.openCustomTab(
    url: String,
    @ColorRes toolbarColor: Int,
    @ColorRes iconColor: Int,
    @DrawableRes drawable: Int
) {
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder().let { ctb ->
        AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, drawable)?.let {
            DrawableCompat.setTint(it, resources.getColor(iconColor))
            ctb.setCloseButtonIcon(it.toBitmap())
        }
        ctb.setDefaultColorSchemeParams(
            CustomTabColorSchemeParams.Builder()
                .setToolbarColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        toolbarColor,
                    )
                ).build()
        )

        ctb.setShowTitle(true)
    }.build().launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url))
}
```